# How to parse active record hierarchy to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, treeview

I'm trying to implement a treeview in my *institution model* in my rails app, I've added [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to my model which works, and [treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) to my view which also works

But I don't really know the way to send the right data, my view expects a js array like this:

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];
```

I've made a web service to return a text and then call it on loaded:

```
request = $.ajax({
        url: '/get_institutions_tree',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            $('#tree').treeview({data: data});
        }
    });
```

But I dont really know how to construct the array, I'm trying to manually parse it, I have this in my controller (I'll try to make it recursive somehow later):

```
def get_institutions_tree
    institutions = Institution.roots

    data = "var data = [ "
    institutions.each do |institution|
      data << get_subtree(institution)
    end
    data << " ];"

    render json: data
  end

  private

  def get_subtree(institution)
    subdata =  "{"
    subdata << "text: '" << institution.name << "',"
    subdata << "}"
  end
```

which for now the web service is returning this (1 depth), but it returns a text ("string") and it doesn't work if I just assign it:

```
var data = [ {text: 'Nacional Bogota',}{text: 'Nacional Cali',} ];
```

How can I make this work? Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the ancestry or treeview gems, but it seems you are building an array of json objects as a string, while you could do it using array and json objects.

In the institutions loops, I would fill an array of roots. Something like:

```
data = []
institutions.each do |institution|
  data << get_subtree(institution)
end
```

Then, the get_subtree should be recursive, to get all levels. And it should build a json. Something like:

```
def get_subtree(institution)
  sub = { :text => institution.name }
  children = institution.children
  if children
    sub.nodes = []
    children.each do |child|
      sub.nodes << get_subtree(child)
    end
  end
  sub
end
```